# Some book recommendations on projective geometry

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, projective-geometry

I want to learn projective geometry for a few months now, especially to understand elliptic curves. I am not completely new to the field, but I need to clear up some concepts, so I could use an introductory book.
I am also interested in the topic of finite projective planes and projective planes over rings. Is there any not-much-involved book on these accounts?
Thanks a lot for your tips.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest Peter Dembowski's *Finite Geometries*.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some interest in projective geometry, so I read the book "Rational points on elliptical curves" by Silverman.  The book is easy but interesting, indeed that's the only book I have read :P

Comment: As well as [Silverman's AEC](https://www.google.fr/search?q=silverman+the+arithmetic+of+elliptic+curves+pdf)